# What are the recommended values and meaning of the WCF Throttling counters?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, performancecounter, throttling

I have a WCF running service with throttling values as

**MaxConcurrentCalls = 32 

MaxConcurrentSessions = 20

MaxConcurrentInstances = 52**

The way I understood the counters is that Concurrent calls govern the number of requests currently being executed, Concurrent sessions govern the number of requests in wait queue and concurrent instances is the sum of both.

We have a scenario, where the Percent of concurrent calls are going > 100 but the percent of concurrent session is always 0.

I am deeply confused about the meaning of these counters and the values I am getting.

Any Help, is appreciated

Comment: Is your service session-enabled?  If it's not, 0 makes sense.  What is the number for concurrent instances?  If it's the same as concurrent calls, then again, 0 makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

**Three points to check in order to have a session**

**1 Use a session enabled binding**

For instance, check that you aren't using `basicHttpBinding` for instance. That binding doesn't support sessions.

Prefer `wsHttpBinding` or `netTcpBinding` or `namedPipeBinding`

**2  Enable session on the service implementation**

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class BillingService { ... }
```

**3 Allow or requires the session on the service interface**

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode=SessionMode.Allowed)]
public interface IBillingService { … }
```

**You can check if there is a current session :**

1 Server side

```
string sessionId = OperationContext.Current.SessionId;
```

2 Client side

```
string sessionId = proxy.InnerChannel.SessionId;
```

Regards